# Deployment error after upgrading to java8 (GAE Standard Environment)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-8

I upgraded my existing application to `java8` runtime in `appengine-web.xml` and recompiled it using latest Java `JDK`. I have also upgraded to latest `GAE SDK (1.9.54).`

No compilation issues but when I deploy it then it is stuck on "Verifying availability: Will check again in 60 seconds. Will check again in 60 seconds."... Logs on Cloud Console are about `Memcache` and `NoSuchMethod` (com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.StatsProtos) :

> com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyLogger warn: Error for
>   /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs (JettyLogger.java:29)
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.StatsProtos$RequestStatProto.getDescriptor()Lcom/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors$Descriptor;
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.MemcacheWriter.persist(MemcacheWriter.java:264)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.MemcacheWriter.commit(MemcacheWriter.java:189)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.Recording.commit(Recording.java:77)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.doFilter(AppstatsFilter.java:154)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:297)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:219)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:81)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:108)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:657)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:619)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:589)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:783)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:263)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Error for
>   /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.StatsProtos$RequestStatProto.getDescriptor()Lcom/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors$Descriptor;
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.MemcacheWriter.persist(MemcacheWriter.java:264)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.MemcacheWriter.commit(MemcacheWriter.java:189)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.Recording.commit(Recording.java:77)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.doFilter(AppstatsFilter.java:154)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:297)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:219)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:81)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:108)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:657)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:619)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:589)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:783)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:263)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Uncaught exception from
>   servlet java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.StatsProtos$RequestStatProto.getDescriptor()Lcom/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors$Descriptor;
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.MemcacheWriter.persist(MemcacheWriter.java:264)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.MemcacheWriter.commit(MemcacheWriter.java:189)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.Recording.commit(Recording.java:77)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.doFilter(AppstatsFilter.java:154)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:297)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:219)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:81)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:108)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:657)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:619)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:589)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:783)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:263)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you solve the problem?